# Рекурсивный обход массива

Tags: php

имеются данные из бд.

```
id = 1
parent_id = 0   

id = 2
parent_id = 1    

id = 3
parent_id = 2
value = 22

id = 4
parent_id = 2
value = 23
```

понятно что для первого родителя можно получить сумму через parent_id

а вот как быть с более глубокой вложенностью? 1 = 2 = (3 + 4)

при этом глубина дерева не известна

примерно такой массив

```
    [1] => 
        [
         [name] = 12,
         [id_par] = 0,   
        ],
    [2] => 
        [
         [name] = 12,
         [id_par] = 1,      
        ],
    [3] => 
        [
         [name] = 12,
         [id_par] = 1,   
        ],
    [4] => 
        [
         [name] = 12,
         [id_par] = 2,
         [val] = 100     
        ],
    [5] => 
        [
         [name] = 12,
         [id_par] = 2,
         [val] = 200    
        ],
    [6] => 
        [
         [name] = 12,
         [id_par] = 3,
         [val] = 100     
        ],
    [7] => 
        [
         [name] = 12,
         [id_par] = 3,
         [val] = 200    
        ],
```

т.е. 1 = (2 + 3) = (4 + 5) + (6 + 7)

Comment: покажите реальную структуру массива, там ничего сложного не должно быть и объясните, что считаем :) - все дерево или по каким-то условиям

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Входные данные:

```
$data = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'parent_id' => null, 'value' => 0),
    array('id' => 2, 'parent_id' => 1, 'value' => 10),
    array('id' => 3, 'parent_id' => 1, 'value' => 20),
    array('id' => 4, 'parent_id' => 2),
);
```

Рекурсивная функция поиска:

```
function search($data, & $current, $parent = null)
{
    foreach ($data as $item) {
        if ($item['parent_id'] == $parent) {
            $value = isset($item['value']) ? $item['value'] : 0;
            $current += $value;
            search($data, $current, $item['id']);
        }
    }
    return $current;
}
```

Использование:

```
$current = 0;
echo search($data, $current, 1); // => 30, где 1 - ид верхнего предка
```

Comment: а если несколько параметров? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/498633/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Comment: @des1roer, ответил...