# Рекурсивное среднее значение

Tags: php

необходимо рассчитать среднее по формуле рекурсивно

(x1*y1 + x2*y2 + x3*y3)/(x1+x2+x3)

```
            function search2($data, & $xy, & $sumx, $parent = null)
            {
                foreach ($data as $item)
                {
                    if ($item['parent_id'] == $parent)
                    {
                        if (!empty($item['valuex']) && !empty($item['valuex']))
                        {
                             $xy += $item['valuex'] * $item['valuey'];                                 
                             $sumx += $item['valuex'];                                
                        }
                        search($data, $xy, $sumx, $item['id']);
                    }
                }
                return $xy/$sumx;
            }
```

таким образом находит только для первого потомка, а общего предка нет.

для массива

```
array(13) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(64)
    ["parent_id"]=>
    int(24)
    ["valuex"]=>
    string(3) "324"
    ["valuey"]=>
    string(3) "324"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(63)
    ["parent_id"]=>
    int(24)
    ["valuex"]=>
    NULL
    ["valuey"]=>
    NULL
  }
```

переработано [Рекурсивный обход массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/498567/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0)

Comment: ` ["valuex"]=>
    NULL
    ["valuey"]=>
    NULL ` так тут null  а у вас проверка на `empty($item['valuex'])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Данные**:

```
$array = array(
    0 => array('id' => 62, 'parent_id' => 24, 'valuex' => 1, 'valuey' => 2),
    1 => array('id' => 63, 'parent_id' => 24, 'valuex' => 3, 'valuey' => 4),
    2 => array('id' => 64, 'parent_id' => 24, 'valuex' => 5, 'valuey' => 6),
    3 => array('id' => 65, 'parent_id' => 63, 'valuex' => 7, 'valuey' => 8),
);
```

**Код**:

```
function search2($data, & $sumOfXAndY, & $sumOfX, $parent = null)
{
    foreach ($data as $item) {
        if ($item['parent_id'] == $parent) {
            if (!empty($item['valuex']) && !empty($item['valuey'])) {
                $sumOfXAndY += $item['valuex'] * $item['valuey'];
                $sumOfX += $item['valuex'];
            }
            search2($data, $sumOfXAndY, $sumOfX, $item['id']);
        }
    }
    return $sumOfXAndY / $sumOfX;
}
```

**Результат**:

```
$sumOfXAndY = $sumOfX = 0;
echo search2($array, $sumOfXAndY, $sumOfX, 24); // => 100 / 16 => 6.25
```